# Bringing metals into home on Saturday

Tags: scripture, belief

There is a popular belief that one should not bring metals (iron afaik) into the home on Saturday.

Is this belief a valid one according to scriptures? If yes, what are the metals mentioned and is there any mention of underlying reason?

Comment: This is related to astrology. Suppose for a particular native Shani Graha is malefic. Then that person must not buy things related to Shani or acquire the same on his day (i.e. on Saturday). Because that just helps Shani to cause more harm to that native. Instead he should do charity of the same things on the same day. And, iron, coal, etc are owned by (or things related to) Shani.